Designing a Rational Function
Design a rational function that has a hole in the graph at $(1, 1)$; has a horizontal asymptote of $y = 0$; has vertical asymptotes at $x = -3$ and $x = 2$; and has a y-intercept of $(0, 5/6)$.
$$\\$$
$$f(x) = \frac{\mathbf{a}(x-1)\mathbf{(x-c)}}{(x-1)(x+3)(x-2)} $$
$$\\$$
$$f(0) = \frac{5}{6}\implies \frac{a(0-1)(0-c)}{(-1)(3)(-2)} = \frac{5}{6}\implies\frac{ac}{6}=\frac{5}{6}\implies ac=5$$
$\\$
$$f(x) = \frac{a(x-c)}{(x+3)(x-2)}$$
$$
f(1) = 1 \implies \frac{a(1-c)}{4(-1)} = 1\implies a-ac=-4
$$
$$\\$$
$$
-4 = a - 5 \implies a = 1
$$
$$
5 = 1 \cdot c \implies c = 5
$$
$$\\$$
$$f(x) = \frac{(x-1)(x-5)}{(x-1)(x+3)(x-2)} 
$$
$$$$

I am having trouble understanding why $a$ and $(x-c)$ specifically were put in.

This is hard to read.  If you think those free parameters are unnecessary, then try to solve the problem without using them.    Problems like this are likely to have multiple solutions and multiples ways of getting at individual solutions.

Well, you need $f(0)=\frac56$, and $f(x)$ to approach $1$ from either side when $x\to 1$.  To accommodate these conditions, you need a constant $a$ (to be determined) and another term $x-c$ (again to be determined).  If $x-c$  is in denominator, it would introduce another vertical asymptote (which presumably is not wanted), so it should be in the numerator. If more vertical asymptotes are allowed, there would be multiple solutions for this.
